# What are these "GENTEX" things on my walls?

Tags: junction-box

My condo has these devices installed in each bedroom and in the living room; but I have no idea what they're for.

[image: GENTEX plate]

Comment: Gentex is the up and coming consumer demographic from Texas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the [Gentex GX90](https://www.firelite.com/CatalogDocuments/df-51573.pdf) Remote Audible Signal which *can* be used as a fire alarm.

It probably is a fire alarm because I could only find references that mention use as a fire alarm, but I presume it could be used for something else.  I say that because they also offer a **"Fire Alarm Red"** color which would imply the off-white version could be used for something other than a fire alarm, e.g. tornado siren.

Comment: I'd say the reason it's white is because someone painted the wall and painted over it, not because it's a different model. You can see in the photo there's fresh white paint on it at the top, if those layers are removed there'll be red colouring underneath

Comment: @TomJNowell I dispute that because the *data sheet* says it comes in Off-White, the walls are a different color than it (and you can see a tiny splotch of paint in the top left), and it is illegal (in the USA where GETNEX is based) to paint fire alarms.

Comment: Yeah, its the most terrible paint job known to man. They painted it to sell it and I wish they had just left it alone.

Answer (score 6):

It's an audible alarm for the buildings fire alarm.